# Finding a hyperbolic metric with geodesic boundary on a given Riemann surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface with analytic boundary. Assume that $X$ has negative Euler characteristic. Then there exists a conformal hyperbolic metric $X$ such that $\partial X$ consists of geodesics (conformal in the sense of being compatible with the given complex structure on $X$).

Does anyone has a reference (or even better, a quick proof) of this result?

Edit: Let me state a stronger version. Suppose $X$ is embedded in an open Riemann surface $Y$. Then there exists a conformal hyperbolic metric on a neighborhood of $X$ in $Y$ such that $\partial X$ consists of geodesics. Is this true?

Comment: The 1992 book: P. Buser, Geometry and Spectra of Compact Riemann Surfaces?

Comment: The stronger version also holds: actually a neighborhood N of X (in the doubling of X) also embeds into Y. Indeed by the Schwarz reflection principle the embedding of X into Y extends to a holomorphic map from a neighborhood N into Y. This extension is an embedding, if N is sufficiently small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good reference is

W. Abikoff, The real analytic theory of Teichmuller space, Springer, 1980. (Chap. II section 1).

The idea is that you construct the double: it is the result of gluing of your surface with its mirror image. This is a compact surface, it has a hyperbolic metric, and the restriction of this metric on the original surface is the hyperbolic metric with geodesic boundary.

Answer (score 5):

See Theorem 1(b) in the following paper; it is enough that the boundary is smooth.

Osgood, B.; Phillips, R.; Sarnak, P. *[Extremals of determinants of Laplacians](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(88)90070-5)*. J. Funct. Anal. 80 (1988), no. 1, 148--211.

Comment: But analyticity of the boundary is necessary. Consider, e.g., a pair of pants. If every pair of pants admits such a metric, then they would be isomorphic to a standard hyperbolic pair of pants, which already has analytic boundary. I guess a more precise way of stating what I'm looking for is that the hyperbolic metric should extend to a hyperbolic metric in a neighborhood of $X$ (after embedding $X$ in an open Riemann surface).

Comment: @YuxiaoXie: You are wrong (confusing different categories: Your question was in differential geometry category and now you are switching to a related, but different category of bordered Riemann surfaces).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't understand why my question was in the differential category. I work on a given Riemann surface and I only consider conformal metrics on it.